# We want to have 2 "Sprints" going at the same time (Admin and Dev)?

Tags: jira

Before we were able to have 2 Sprints on a Single Project at the same time ("Dev" and "Admin"). One was for Administrative tasks, the other for development tasks. They would start and end at the same time. 
For example:

Sprint 4 - Admin: 06/01/2014 - 06/15/2014
Sprint 4 - Dev: 06/01/2014 - 06/15/2014
Sprint 5 - Admin: 06/16/2014 - 06/31/2014
Sprint 5 - Dev: 06/16/2014 - 06/31/2014

Now, whenever we start a sprint (ex: Sprint 5 - Admin), and try to start another Sprint that is in the same time slot, it says that the new sprint cannot be start until the previous one is completed (whenever hovering over "Start Sprint")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the JIRA Agile Labs Parallel Sprints feature. Looks like someone may have disabled it for you

Comment: Genius :) That fixed it https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/How+do+I+have+multiple+or+parallel+sprints+running+at+the+same+time